# Doctrine 2: how to clone all values from one object onto another except ID?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony

In $entity variable, there is an object of same type as $other_address, but with all field values filled in.

I want to set all fields in $other_address object to have exact same values as $entity object.

Is this doable in less then N number of lines, where N is number of fields I need to set?

I tried "clone" keyword, but it didnt work.

Here's the code.

```
                $other_address = $em->getRepository('PennyHomeBundle:Address')
          ->findBy(array('user' => $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId(), 'type' => $check_type));
                $other_address = $other_address[0];


                //I want to set all values in this object to have values from another object of same type
                $other_address->setName($entity->getName());
                $other_address->setAddress1($entity->getAddress1());
                $other_address->setAddress2($entity->getAddress2());
                $other_address->setSuburbTown($entity->getSuburbTown());
                $other_address->setCityState($entity->getCityState());
                $other_address->setPostZipCode($entity->getPostZipCode());
                $other_address->setPhone($entity->getPhone());
                $other_address->setType($check_type);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm not sure why cloning won't work.

This seems to work for me, at least in a basic test case:

```
$A = $em->find('Some\Entity',1);

$B = clone $A;
$B->setId(null);
```

If you've got relationships to worry about, you might want to [safely implement __clone](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html#safely-implementing-clone) so it does what you want it to do with related entities.

Comment: As DavidLin points, you don't have to "unset" the entity ID (if the field is properly marked as ID)

Comment: HI @timdev, what if i wanted to copy, assume i have a temp object and i need to merge that it in original object? is that possible?

Answer (score 29):

Just Clone the entity, you don't even need to unset the id. Doctrine has tackled this for you

Comment: It seems that if you use your own ID generators the ID isn't set to null. Even if the ID field is marked as being an ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
$A = $em->find('Some\Entity',1);

$B = clone $A;
$em->persist($B);
$em->flush();
```

if you `merge` it will update the entity, best you use `persist()` it will duplicate the entire row and add auto incremented primary key