# Deep cloning an object : Clone vs Serialize

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, clone

I have this function duplicateCourseAction whose goal is to ... duplicate a Course object

```
public function duplicateCourseAction(Request $request) {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() == false) {
        return new Response("Bad request", 405);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $parameters = $request->request->all();
    $course = $em->getRepository('EntTimeBundle:Course')->findOneById($parameters['id']);
    $duplicate = clone $course;
    $duplicate->setDate(new \DateTime($parameters['date']));
    $em->persist($duplicate);
    $em->flush();
    return new Response("200");
}
```

According to documentations, "clone" keyword make a surface copy (ie. a reference copy).
This is clearly not what I want because my Course entity contains many relations to others entities, I would rather want a values copy.

I discovered the unserialize(serialize(object)) trick :

```
public function duplicateCourseAction(Request $request) {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() == false) {
        return new Response("Bad request", 405);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $parameters = $request->request->all();
    $course = $em->getRepository('EntTimeBundle:Course')->findOneById($parameters['id']);
    $duplicate = unserialize(serialize($course));
    $duplicate->setDate(new \DateTime($parameters['date']));
    $em->persist($duplicate);
    $em->flush();
    return new Response("200");
}
```

But I have this error with Doctrine :

**Notice: Undefined index: 000000003ed2e9ea00000000ee270fde in /home/mart_q/Diderot/ent/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2776**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control what exactly gets cloned by overriding the `__clone()` method in your `Course` entity. You can set `id` to `null` and clone referenced objects if you need a deep copy.

The serialization/unserialization feels like a hack, so I recommend against using it.

Comment: I'm doing this : `public function __clone() {
        $this->id = null;
        $this->teachers = clone $this->teachers;
    }` But I have : FatalErrorException: Error: __clone method called on non-object. Is this beacause teachers is an ArrayCollection() ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've provided. Try and fail and try again, debug, comment out different parts of code to see what's failing. I've put you on the right path, but you need to figure out the details yourself.

Comment: I already testes __clone() before, but if you say me this is the right way, i'll try to figure out what is going wrong by myself. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Trick here is that you must unset duplicate entity id. Otherwise breaks the logic of the doctrine. Doctrine has some known [limitations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#entities). Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533695/doctrine-2-how-to-clone-all-values-from-one-object-onto-another-except-id), its very similar.

Comment: I already tested to unset entity id. You want me to do this for clone or serialize method ?

Comment: `$B = clone $A; $B->setId(null);`