# Creating a clone of an object, but of a class that inherits the original one

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, instance

In the given scenario, i have a class:

```
class shopCart {}
```

I use *destructors* and *constructors* in there, to perform certain actions.

Later on, i want to store a serialized version of the cart. However, the object i serialize should **not** incorporate the *destructor* and *constructor* methods.

In order to achieve this, i created a class:

```
class storageCart extends shopCart {
    function __construct(){}
    function __destruct(){}
}
```

Now, before i store the cart, i must create a new object of type `storageCart` and make sure it contains all the properties of `shopCart`.

To fulfill this need, `shopCart` has a method `getInstanceForStorage()`:

```
public function getInstanceForStorage() {
    $storageCart = new storageCart();
    foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $k => $v){
        $storageCart->{$k}=$v;
    }
    return $storageCart;
}
```

The problem is that changes i make to the new instance (`storageCart`) seem to affect the original instance (`shopCart`).

It is important to mention here, that one of the variables of `shopCart` is an array containing objects (cart items).

I assume i ran into some object / instancing / copying / cloning (or lack thereof) mess. But i don't know what the problem could be, because i do not use pointers in my assignment in the above `foreach` loop.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening here?

Note: This is PHP > 5.3

**EDIT**

I tried copying the contents of the array which contains the objects, by assigning them to the same array in the new object and using `clone`, but - to my surprise - i still end up with a reference. I don't understand.

Is it perhaps possible, that objects within the cloned objects are still references to the original objects?

Comment: Yes they are, you need to do a [deep clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592872/deep-cloning-an-object-clone-vs-serialize) if you want those properties to be clones rather than references

Comment: Oh. Is it safe then, to recursively run through an object's properties, looking for deeper objects, and then copying clones onto themselves?

Comment: Perfectly safe, and the recommended technique in this case, because you're not copying them onto themselves, you're creating new clones instances within the clone.... the originals remain intact within the original parent

Comment: Awesome. Mind posting as an answer so we can close this accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you want is called making a "deep clone", and can be implemented easily using the [__clone()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)  magic method in your objects:

```
/**
 * Implement PHP __clone to create a deep clone, not just a shallow copy.
 */
public function __clone()
{
    foreach ($this as $key => $val) {
        if (is_object($val) || (is_array($val))) {
            $this->{$key} = clone $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Just define this in your main class, and in the classes of all the objects that you store as properties in that class, all the way down

Of course, if you hold an array of objects as a property, you'll need to adapt this code to walk that array as well